porque esta funcion no se ejecuta (react)
tengo una función la cual se encuentra dentro del return del react ,pero por alguna razon no se ejecuta aunque las animaciones se muestren en pantalla y finalicen, tengo una tal que muestra una animacion de una imagen cualquiera con una animación simple de css :
const ImageAnimation = ({ imageSrc, animationClass }) => {
  return (
    <div className={`image-animation ${animationClass}`}>
      <img src={imageSrc} alt="Animated" />
    </div>
  );
};

pero luego al intentar accionar un evento al finalizar esa animacion nunca se genera:

return ({animations.map(animation => (
      <ImageAnimation
        key={animation.id}
        imageSrc={animation.src}
        animationClass={animation.animationClass}
        onAnimationEnd={() => {
          const currentIndex = animations.findIndex(anim => anim.id === animation.id);
          if (currentIndex !== -1) {
            const sectionIndex = selectedSong.numberSequence[currentIndex] - 1;
            handleAnimationEnd(sectionIndex);
          }
        }}
      />
    ))}
)

con animación simple de css me refiero una como esta:
.slideFromRight {
  right: -200px;
  animation: slideFromRight 6s forwards;
}

@keyframes slideFromRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0;
  }90% {
    opacity: 1;
    right: calc(40%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    right: calc(50%);
  }
}


Lee tambien Como crear un ejemplo completo, minimo y verificable

@infinit3Loop__ perdona es que si coloco el codigo no me deja publicar porque dice mayormente codigo ,intentare eliminado el css

Agrega el minimo codigo necesario para reproducir el problema, como dice en el enlace. Lo que no este relacionado directamente con el problema eliminalo.

@infinit3Loop__ entiendo, te refieres asi?

no, lee bien el enlace que te mande, una persona que intenta ayudarte y que no tiene tu codigo no puede reproducir el problema, ese es el punto. Disculpa por ser tan pesado, pero para que te ayuden en este sitio hay que poner de nuestra parte, las pocas veces que hago preguntas aqui intento hacer lo mismo.

@infinit3Loop__ entiendo la verdad es mi primera vez en el sitio, intente explicarlo un poco mejor

finalmente pude solucionarlo agregando un event listener a la primera funcion:

const ImageAnimation = ({ imageSrc, animationClass, onAnimationEnd }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const element = document.querySelector(`.${animationClass}`);
    element.addEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEnd);

    return () => {
      element.removeEventListener('animationend', onAnimationEnd);
    };
  }, [animationClass, onAnimationEnd]);

  return (
    <div className={`image-animation ${animationClass}`}>
      <img src={imageSrc} alt="Animated" />
    </div>
  );
};

